# Swift: Label text Issues ( Getting Different Count of Same Array) Response from API

Tags: ios, json, swift, api

I'm developing a Bus Ticket Booking app. I'm trying to show the text on my **label** as per the following image.

[image]

So when the user fills the required data (Source City, Destination city and the Date of the journey) and hits Submit Button, the next `UIViewController` is presented with the filter Bus route on that particular Date.

[image]

But every time the **label** shows 0 count. The following is my code for the label text.

> Label Code:

```
func setValues() {
    let count2 = routes.count
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        self.lblRoute.text = (String(count2) + "Trip(s) Available on" + Utill.getStringFromDate("  dd MMMM yyyy,EEEE", date: self.currentDate))
    }
}
```

And I call this function in `viewDidLoad()`. I use the same array Count for my `numberOfRowsInSection` tableView method. Here is Code table method Code.

> TableView Method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return routes.count
}
```

But it's now showing 0, I get the proper count(4) for my `numberOfRow` as you can see in the image.

So why it's showing the different count of the same Array? Is there any Concurrency issue like that?

Comment: Most likely it's an issue related to asynchronous data processing. And delete `[unowned self]`. It has no effect.

Comment: where is your api call?

Comment: ST bus ma avuj thay! :)

Comment: So what is the final code ? @vadian

Comment: The final code depends on your code where `setValues()` is called. But this code is missing in the question.

Comment: i just simply call the `setValue()` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: You have to call `setValue` **after** filtering the bus routes right before calling `reloadData()`.

Comment: yes that i understand but how? can I call in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea because the relevant code is missing and I can't read your mind. Is *after filtering the bus routes* not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Actually mutable array's count is depend on time, i mean it mutated like below

```
var routes = [0,1,2]
print(routes.count) // 3

arr = []
print(routes.count) // 0
```

Batter approach is:

```
var routes:[Trip] = [] {
    didSet {
        setValues() // update ui
    }
}
```